# Lines not ending on nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have three nodes:

```
\draw (4,2) node(p1)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
\draw (5,3) node(p2)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
\draw (6,4) node(p3)[label={[label distance=0.0cm]0:$$}]{};
```

that I try to connect with:

```
\draw[help lines] (p1) -- (p2);
\draw[help lines] (p2) -- (p3);
```

but the lines are not ending exactly on those nodes. Someone know why?

I am including also the header files because it is a long list and I am not really able to understand where the problem could come from:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{subcaption}


%%% List of packages used
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{quickdecim}
\usepackage{tikz} %for drawings:
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections,plotmarks}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
 \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/axis labels at tip/.style={ % This defines the axis as I want
  xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, xshift=10cm, yshift=-10cm, anchor=center},
  ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, yshift=10cm, xshift=-10cm, anchor=center}}
} 

\usepackage{tkz-fct}     %for functions
%%% Up to here


\parindent=0pt 

%FLOW CHART packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}


% For Arrow Head Filled
\tikzset{>=latex}


%++++++++++++++++++
% For Hatch
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%++++++++++++++++++


             \usepackage[noheadfoot,nomarginpar,margin=1mm,paperwidth=9cm,paperheight=6cm]{geometry} 

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
  every path/.style = {scale = 0.52},
  every node/.append style = {font=\sffamily,scale = 1.0},
  ]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-1.2,-0.2)}]{
   \draw (4,2) node(p1)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
   \draw (5,3) node(p2)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
   \draw (6,4) node(p3)[label={[label distance=0.0cm]0:$$}]{}; 
   \draw[help lines] (p1) -- (p2);
   \draw[help lines] (p2) -- (p3);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate if someone with can help me with this trivial problem.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Note also that the order of `\end{figure}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` is wrong in your code.

Comment: I'll re-edit the question. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines do end at the nodes, you have to consider that nodes have some padding (`inner sep`, `outer sep`), and lines are drawn to the edge of the node, not the center. Add `draw` to the node options and you'll see this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,2) node(p1)[draw,label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
\draw (5,3) node(p2)[draw,label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]{}; 
\draw (6,4) node(p3)[draw,label={[label distance=0.0cm]0:$$}]{}; 

\draw[help lines] (p1) -- (p2);
\draw[help lines] (p2) -- (p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a full line you can draw the line between the `center` anchors, i.e.

```
\draw[help lines] (p1.center) -- (p2.center) -- (p3.center);
```

or you can use `coordinate` instead of `node`, i.e.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
  every path/.style = {scale = 0.52},
  every node/.append style = {font=\sffamily,scale = 1.0},
  ]
\draw (4,2) coordinate(p1)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]; 
\draw (5,3) coordinate(p2)[label={[label distance=0.9cm]0:$$}]; 
\draw (6,4) coordinate(p3)[label={[label distance=0.0cm]0:$$}]; 

\draw[help lines] (p1) -- (p2);
\draw[help lines] (p2) -- (p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. It's exactly the explanation I was looking for. :)

Comment: And again, thanks for the effort, I like when explanation  are given other than just the solution.

Comment: See also: [TikZ minimal node size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628075/tikz-minimal-node-size)