# Tikz arrows and lines not touching nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the tikz package, and the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \node (A) at (-2.3,-3){};
    \node (B) at (-2.3,3){};
    \node (bb) at (0,3){};
    \draw[-] (B) -- (bb) node[] {};
    \draw[>=latex,<->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,left] {$D_u$};
    \node (C) at (-1,-2){};
    \node (D) at (-1,2){};
    \node (dd) at (0,2){};
    \node (cc) at (0,-2){};
    \node (aa) at (-1,-3){};
    \node (ee) at (0,-3){};
   \draw[-] (D) -- (dd) node[]{};
   \draw[-] (C) -- (cc) node[]{}; 
   \draw[-] (A) -- (aa) node[]{};
   \draw[-] (aa) -- (ee) node[]{};
   \draw[>=latex,<->] (C) -- (D) node[midway,left] {$D_i$};
   \draw[>=latex,<->] (C) -- (aa) node[midway,left]
{$e_{\text{min}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For some reason, the arrows and lines are too short as shown in the picture. This is my first time using the package, from what I've seen in other examples, people have proper lines and arrows, so I can't figure out what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Just use ‘\coordinate’ instead of ‘\node’

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lines not ending on nodes with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291979/lines-not-ending-on-nodes-with-tikz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a `\node` is an invisible rectangle that can contain text. If no text is provided, it is still a rectangle that has a minimum nonzero size. If you want your nodes to be points, use `\node [coordinate]`.

You can also remove all the empty `node[] {};` at the end of your `\draw` commands. Those are only needed if you want to put some text/node at the end of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \node [coordinate] (A) at (-2.3,-3){};
    \node [coordinate] (B) at (-2.3,3){};
    \node (bb) at (0,3){};
    \draw[-] (B) -- (bb);
    \draw[>=latex,<->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,left] {$D_u$};
    \node [coordinate] (C) at (-1,-2){};
    \node [coordinate] (D) at (-1,2){};
    \node [coordinate] (dd) at (0,2){};
    \node [coordinate] (cc) at (0,-2){};
    \node [coordinate] (aa) at (-1,-3){};
    \node [coordinate] (ee) at (0,-3){};
   \draw[-] (D) -- (dd);
   \draw[-] (C) -- (cc); 
   \draw[-] (A) -- (aa);
   \draw[-] (aa) -- (ee);
   \draw[>=latex,<->] (C) -- (D) node[midway,left] {$D_i$};
   \draw[>=latex,<->] (C) -- (aa) node[midway,left]
{$e_{\text{min}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]