# TikZ minimal node size

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Even after setting `text width=0pt, text height=0pt, inner sep=0pt` as node parameters, and giving empty label, the node still has nonzero size. It seems to have both height and width equal 1 pt, as seen in the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ultra thin,draw,text width=0pt,text height=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};

\draw[ultra thin] (1pt,-.5pt)--(1pt,.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is it so? Is there any secret parameter adding 1 pt to spacing? Is it possible to change it and produce smaller nodes?

Comment: @Zarko I know I can use coordinates as dimensionless points, but I'm wondering what mechanism limits `\node`'s size from below. (Side note: `\coordinate (a) at (0,0);` works without empty braces at the end too)

Comment: @you are right ... when I convert `\node[coordinate] (a) at (0,0);`  (which is solution for what you looking for) to `\coordinate (a) at (0,0);` i forgot to delete `{}`. Why is so? You should ask package designer, it is his decision.

Comment: Sorry, your question after editing become unclear. What is your problem? You cannot draw node borders around node of zero size. What influence on node size is clearly stated in my answer.

Comment: @Zarko you're of course right, I made a mistake when copying your answer to test it and it seemed that the borders are still drawn around zero size node which is not the case if we set all minimum size, inner sep and outer sep to 0pt. Sorry for the confusion, I deleted the edit, I hope the question is clear now

Comment: More important is that my answer is clear to you ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node size is determines by: `minimum size` (or `minimum width`, `minimum height`, etc., `inner sep` and `outer sep`. If you set them to zero, than node become equivalent to `\coordinate`. For comparison see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (a) at (0,0)  {};
\draw[red] (a) -- + (2pt,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (1pt,-.5pt) -- (1pt,.5pt);

\scoped[yshift=1mm]
{
\node[coordinate] (a) at (0,0)  {};
\draw[red] (a) -- + (2pt,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (1pt,-.5pt) -- (1pt,.5pt);
}

\scoped[yshift=2mm]
{
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\draw[red] (a) -- + (2pt,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (1pt,-.5pt) -- (1pt,.5pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At all cases the result is the same. The `\coordinate` is actually a node of zero size as is determined in the first example.

[image]

Comment: Always perfect your answer

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much for nice words, but your praise is a little exaggerated ;-). Marry Christmas and Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually meant something slightly different - the size of the shape drawn by \node[draw... (see edit in the original post). But your answer is also useful to see where line starts when we use node as endpoint